# TCP&UDP Networking Library Design

Tags: c#, networking, socket, tcp, udp

Edit: This question is dead, so I am making an edit in hopes that someone who does have the time to look over my code sees it. If you have any way for me to improve this question/ask some other community/have some recommendations on how I might get an answer (sadly cannot set a bounty due to my points) please tell me. Thanks

I am writing a small c# networking library that should be able to do UDP and TCP, but I am afraid I am in way over my head. It works now (both TCP as well as UDP can transmit and receive messages at a decently high rate) but I am certain I have some very big architectural misconceptions (as well as a variety of bugs etc). This is the first bit of Networking I have done and on the web there is a lot of conflicting ideas/recommendations floating around, which is why I wanted to get some feedback on what I am doing.

Also, just a disclaimer: My terminology is very wrong (like UDP is connectionless and TCP is stream-based but my code still refers to Packets and Connections). Since this is just a personal project of mine I must admit I focused more on getting it working and the big architectural issues than the conventions and terminology. Sorry :/

Here is the high-level architectural idea of the library:

It aims to provide a simple interface that hides all the complexity that comes from establishing connections of any kind. For now, the library only implements Network Connections over TCP and UDP but the idea is that over the `Connection` class even other Connection Types (like Serial etc.) could later be added.

- The `Connection` class is only a boiler plate declaring `Write(message)` and stores a packet handler method that gets called when a message is received.
- `NetworkConnection` (inheriting from Connection) is the base for all Network-Based Connections (TcpConnection, UdpConnection). It is responible for maintaining the write-queue and owns the socket
- `TcpConnection` and `UdpConnection` (both inherit from NetworkConnection) do all the protocol-specific work (especially reading). Messages in both protocols have size prefixes (since multiple messages can be sent in one Datagram)

The reading and writing for each connection has its own thread. Depending on the configuration, received messages in the thread are either handled in order and directly in the IO thread or out of order in their own threads.

These are some things that I think might be problematic (but I don't know how to do it differently):

- There must be an easier way to implement all this (without an external library). But I don't know the unnecessary detours I might have taken
- Putting UDP and TCP under the same roof proofed difficult, since they are so similar in some regards but not at all in others. Is this attempt at generalizing stupid in general?
- Due to the amount of code and all the edge cases there surely are some very serious bugs
- The code creates a lot of threads, how bad is that overhead and how do I reduce the amount of threads that are created?
- Terminology, Naming Conventions and Readability are sadly not my greatest strengths
- I do not know how big the performance advantage of async Sockets, is writing blocking sockets problematic?

This is A LOT of code sadly so I totally understand if you would rather use your time differently. I am very happy about absolutely every type of feedback, so even if you didn't check the whole code but found an issue please let me know. If this is not enough code for someone, [here](https://github.com/JakobTinhofer/.NET-Networking) is the repo with all files (including tests etc.).

Thank you very mutch for taking a look at this, it helps me a lot.

Code:

- `Connection.cs`:

```
namespace LightBlueFox.Networking
{
    // This describes any connection between two programs, be it over the internet or whatever other communication media.
    public abstract class Connection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A method which handles any incomming packets
        /// </summary>
        public PacketHandler? PacketHandler { get; set; }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets called when the connection is terminated. An exception is provided as the reason for the disconnection.
        /// </summary>
        public event ConnectionDisconnectedHandler? ConnectionDisconnected;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a packet to the program at the other side.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Packet">Just the packet data, no size prefix required.</param>
        public abstract void WritePacket(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Packet);

        public abstract void CloseConnection();

        protected void CallConnectionClosed(Exception? ex)
        {
            Task.Run(() => ConnectionDisconnected?.Invoke(this, ex));
        }

        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Describes a method equiped to handle packets comming from an active <see cref="Connection"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The connection which received the packet.</param>
    /// <param name="packet">The raw data that was received.</param>
    public delegate void PacketHandler(ReadOnlySpan<byte> packet, PacketArgs args);

    /// <summary>
    /// Describes methods which can be used to listen to the <see cref="Connection.ConnectionDisconnected"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The connection that was terminated.</param>
    /// <param name="disconnectionException">The reason for the termination. Null if the connection terminated as planned.</param>
    public delegate void ConnectionDisconnectedHandler(Connection sender, Exception? disconnectionException);
}
```

- `NetworkConnection.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LightBlueFox.Networking
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Describes a connection between to machines over the Internet Protocol (IP).
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class NetworkConnection : Connection
    {
        #region Private Fields
        /// <summary>
        /// The socket that is used to communicate to the remote client with.
        /// </summary>
        protected Socket Socket;
        protected EndPoint _remoteEndpoint;
        protected bool _keepMessagesInOrder;



        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// The endpoint (as seen from the perspective of this device) of the remote client.
        /// Keep in mind, this might not be the actual endpoint of the device (If the connection is using a relay server,
        /// this will be the EndPoint of the mirror server, not the client on the other side)
        /// </summary>
        public IPEndPoint RemoteEndpoint { get { return (IPEndPoint)_remoteEndpoint; } }
        public Protocol Protocol { get; protected set; }

        public abstract bool KeepMessagesInOrder { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Connection from an existing socket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">The already established Socket. Make sure <see cref="Socket.ProtocolType"/> is either <see cref="ProtocolType.Udp"/> or <see cref="ProtocolType.Tcp"/>.</param>
        /// <param name="re">The endpoint of the remote client.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">The given arguments were invalid. This is likely because the given Socket uses an invalid protocol.</exception>
        public NetworkConnection(Socket s, IPEndPoint re)
        {
            if ((s.ProtocolType != ProtocolType.Tcp && s.ProtocolType != ProtocolType.Udp)) throw new ArgumentException("This is not the right protocol. Make sure that your socket uses either udp or tcp!");
            Protocol = (Protocol)s.ProtocolType;
            Socket = s;
            _remoteEndpoint = re;
            OnQueueFlushRequested += FlushWriteQueue;
            KeepMessagesInOrder = true;
        }

        #endregion

        protected abstract void StartListening();

        private ConcurrentQueue<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> writeMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>();



        #region Write Queue Flushing

        /// <summary>
        /// If this many elements are reached in the write queue, a compound packet is sent.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly static int WriteQueueMaxElements = 5;

        /// <summary>
        /// Automatically flush queue every x ms.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly static int WriteQueueFlushInterval = 5;

        static NetworkConnection()
        {
            QueueFlusher();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function requests a new queue flush for all active connections every <see cref="WriteQueueFlushInterval"/> ms.
        /// </summary>
        private static async void QueueFlusher()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(WriteQueueFlushInterval);
                if(OnQueueFlushRequested != null)
                    await Task.Run(OnQueueFlushRequested.Invoke);
            }
        }
        private delegate void QueueFlushRequestedHandler();
        private static event QueueFlushRequestedHandler? OnQueueFlushRequested;

        #endregion

        private readonly Mutex _sendMutex = new Mutex();
        private async void FlushWriteQueue()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                if(!writeMessages.IsEmpty)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ReadOnlyMemory<byte> message;
                        _sendMutex.WaitOne();
                        while (writeMessages.TryDequeue(out message))
                        {
                            // Stay within some safe packet size limits. If we dequeue too much, push it back in (this should preserve the order)
                            if(Protocol == Protocol.UDP &&  ms.Length + message.Length + 4 > 59900)
                            {
                                writeMessages = (ConcurrentQueue<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>)writeMessages.Prepend(message);
                                break;
                            }
                            Span<byte> sizeSpan = new byte[4];
                            BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(sizeSpan, message.Length);
                            ms.Write(sizeSpan);
                            ms.Write(message.Span);
                        }
                        WriteToSocket(ms.ToArray());
                        _sendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Ask the connection to write a new packet to the socket.
        /// </summary>
        public override void WritePacket(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Packet)
        {
            if (IsClosed) throw new InvalidOperationException("Socket is closed.");
            if (Protocol == Protocol.UDP && Packet.Length + 4 > 59900) throw new ArgumentException("A udp message may not be over 59900 bytes in length!");
            writeMessages.Enqueue(Packet);
            if (writeMessages.Count > WriteQueueMaxElements) FlushWriteQueue();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This does the protocol-specific write to the socket.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract void WriteToSocket(byte[] data);

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes the connection and disposes the socket. This will likely trigger the <see cref="Connection.ConnectionDisconnected"/> event with the exception of type <see cref="ObjectDisposedException"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public override void CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                Socket.Close();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
            IsClosed = true;
            OnQueueFlushRequested -= FlushWriteQueue;
        }

        public bool IsClosed { get; private set; } = false;

    }



    public enum Protocol
    {
        TCP = 6,
        UDP = 17,
    }
}
```

- `TcpConnection.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LightBlueFox.Networking
{
    

    public class TcpConnection : NetworkConnection
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="TcpConnection"/> from an existing <see cref="Socket"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s"></param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown if <see cref="Socket.SocketType"/> is not <see cref="SocketType.Stream"/> or <see cref="Socket.ProtocolType"/> is not <see cref="ProtocolType.Tcp"/>.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown if <see cref="Socket.RemoteEndPoint"/> is null.</exception>
        public TcpConnection(Socket s) : base(s, (IPEndPoint)(s.RemoteEndPoint ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("s.RemoteEndpoint")))
        {
            if (s.ProtocolType != ProtocolType.Tcp || s.SocketType != SocketType.Stream) throw new ArgumentException("The given socket does not seem to be a tcp socket!");
            if (s.Connected == false) throw new ArgumentException("The given socket is not connected!");
            StartListening();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new tcp connection from an already established tcp client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        public TcpConnection(TcpClient c) : this(c.Client) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a connection to a given ip and port.
        /// </summary>
        public TcpConnection(string ip, int port) : this(new TcpClient(ip, port)) {
        
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Just writes data to socket stream
        /// </summary>
        protected override void WriteToSocket(byte[] data)
        {
            Socket.Send(data);
        }

        #region Reading

        /// <summary>
        /// Describes how a buffer is to be handled after it was completely received.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">The received buffer.</param>
        private delegate ReadState BufferAction(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer);

        /// <summary>
        /// Describes a buffer that needs to be filled and an action that should be performed once the buffer has been filled.
        /// </summary>
        private class ReadState
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The actual data read.
            /// </summary>
            public byte[] Buffer;

            public int Length;

            public Memory<byte> Data;

            /// <summary>
            /// The index to which will be written next. If this index is equal to the length of <see cref="ReadState.Buffer"/>, the read is finished and <see cref="OnBufferFilled"/> will be called.
            /// </summary>
            public int WriteIndex = 0;

            private static ArrayPool<byte> messageBufferPool = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;
            private static ConcurrentDictionary<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, byte[]> borrowedArrays = new ConcurrentDictionary<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, byte[]>();

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the array corresponding to the given buffer.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="bytes"></param>
            public static void ReturnMemory(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> bytes)
            {
                byte[] byteArray;
                #pragma warning disable CS8600
                if (borrowedArrays.Remove(bytes, out byteArray))
                    messageBufferPool.Return(byteArray, true);
                #pragma warning restore CS8600
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a new readstate representing the next message to be read.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="buffer">The actual buffer rented from the ArrayPool.</param>
            /// <param name="Length">A length equal or smaller that the size of the buffer. This is how many bytes will actually be read.</param>
            /// <param name="action"></param>
            public ReadState(int Length, BufferAction action)
            {
                Buffer = messageBufferPool.Rent(Length);
                this.Length = Length;
                Data = new Memory<byte>(Buffer, 0, Length);
                borrowedArrays.TryAdd(Data, Buffer);
                OnBufferFilled = action;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a new readstate that represents a length prefix to be read.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="buffer"></param>
            /// <param name="action"></param>
            public ReadState(byte[] buffer, BufferAction action)
            {
                Buffer = buffer;
                OnBufferFilled = action;
                Length = 4;
                Data = new Memory<byte>(Buffer, 0, Length);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// The action to perform with the finished buffer.
            /// </summary>
            public BufferAction OnBufferFilled;
        }
        
        private byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[4];

        
        protected async override void StartListening()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                ReadState state = new ReadState(sizeBuffer, SizePrefixAction);
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = Socket.Receive(state.Buffer, state.WriteIndex, state.Length - state.WriteIndex, 0);
                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            state.WriteIndex += bytesRead;
                            if (state.WriteIndex == state.Length)
                            {
                                state = state.OnBufferFilled(state.Data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) when (ex is SocketException || ex is ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    CallConnectionClosed(ex);
                }
                

            });
        }

        #region Message Actions

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the size prefix into an int and rents a buffer from the ArrayPool to which the message will be read.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="prefix">The bytes encoding the length prefix.</param>
        private ReadState SizePrefixAction(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> prefix)
        {
            int len = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(prefix.Span);
            // TODO: Set max packet length!
            return new ReadState(len, MessageAction);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the <see cref="PacketHandler"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private ReadState MessageAction(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> message)
        {
            if (KeepMessagesInOrder)
            {
                messages.Add(message);
            }
            else
            {
                Task.Run(() => { PacketHandler?.Invoke(message.Span, new PacketArgs(this)); ReadState.ReturnMemory(message); });
            }
            return new ReadState(sizeBuffer, SizePrefixAction);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Message Processing

        
        /// <summary>
        /// If true, the <see cref="PacketHandler"/> needs to return before the next message is processed and the handler is called again. Packets received in the meantime will be queued up.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool KeepMessagesInOrder { 
            get {
                return _keepMessagesInOrder;
            } 
            set {
                if (value && (queueWorker == null || queueWorker.IsCompleted))
                {
                    queueWorker = WorkOnQueue();
                }
                
                _keepMessagesInOrder = value;
            } 
        }


        private BlockingCollection<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> messages = new BlockingCollection<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>();
        private Task? queueWorker;
        private async Task WorkOnQueue()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                ReadOnlyMemory<byte> message;
                while (KeepMessagesInOrder || messages.Count > 0){
                    if (messages.TryTake(out message))
                    {
                        PacketHandler?.Invoke(message.Span, new PacketArgs(this));
                        ReadState.ReturnMemory(message);
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}
```

- `UdpConnection.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LightBlueFox.Networking
{
    public class UdpConnection : NetworkConnection
    {
        public UdpConnection(Socket s, IPEndPoint re) : base(s, re)
        {
            StartListening();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If true; waits for one message to finish processing before the next one is passed to the handler
        /// </summary>
        public override bool KeepMessagesInOrder { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Class-Internal representation of one or more messages sent in one datagram
        /// </summary>
        private class UdpMultiMessage
        {
            public static ArrayPool<byte> bufferPool = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;

            public UdpMultiMessage(int messages, byte[] buffer)
            {
                _messages = messages; bufferToReturn = buffer;
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// The number of messages still not handled from this datagram.
            /// </summary>
            private int _messages;

            /// <summary>
            /// Makes sure buffer is returned as soon as all messages are handled.
            /// </summary>
            public int MessagesRemaining { get { return _messages; } set { _messages = value; if (_messages <= 0) bufferPool.Return(bufferToReturn); } }
            private byte[] bufferToReturn;
        }

        private async Task Deconstruct(byte[] datagram, int length, bool mode, UDPPacketArgs args)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                int index = 0;
                int payload_len;
                

                UdpMultiMessage up = new UdpMultiMessage(0, datagram);

                while (index < length)
                {
                    payload_len = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(datagram, index, 4));
                    index += 4;

                    if (payload_len > 0)
                    {
                        ReadOnlyMemory<byte> payload = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(datagram, index, payload_len);
                        //Need to check mode instead of KeepMessagesInOrder since that could have changed between some of the packets
                        if (mode)
                        {
                            PacketHandler?.Invoke(payload.Span, args);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            up.MessagesRemaining += 1;
                            Task.Run(() => { PacketHandler?.Invoke(payload.Span, args); up.MessagesRemaining--; });
                        }

                        index += payload_len;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This buffer is used when messages are kept in order (since the buffer can be overwritten once a message has been handled)
        /// If <see cref="KeepMessagesInOrder"/> is false, buffers are rented from an arraypool.
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] syncBuffer = new byte[60000];
        protected async override void StartListening()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                bool mode = KeepMessagesInOrder;
                byte[] buffer = KeepMessagesInOrder ? syncBuffer : UdpMultiMessage.bufferPool.Rent(60000);
                while (true)
                {
                    
                    try
                    {
                        
                        EndPoint ep = _remoteEndpoint ?? new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                        int len = Socket.ReceiveFrom(syncBuffer, ref ep);
                        
                        
                        if (_remoteEndpoint == null || _remoteEndpoint == ep)
                        {
                            if (len > 0) Deconstruct(syncBuffer, len, mode, new UDPPacketArgs(this, _remoteEndpoint != null, ep)).Wait();
                        }


                        mode = KeepMessagesInOrder;
                        if (!mode && len > 0) buffer = UdpMultiMessage.bufferPool.Rent(60000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is SocketException || ex is ObjectDisposedException)
                    {
                        CallConnectionClosed(ex);
                        return;
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes one or more messages as a single datagram
        /// </summary>
        protected override void WriteToSocket(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_remoteEndpoint == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use Write without knowing the recipient! Either set a default recipient, or use WriteTo!");
                Socket.SendTo(data, _remoteEndpoint);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is SocketException || ex is ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                CallConnectionClosed(ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes to a special recipient ip.
        /// </summary>
        public void WriteTo(byte[] data, EndPoint endPoint)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket.SendTo(data, endPoint);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is SocketException || ex is ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                CallConnectionClosed(ex);
            }
        }


        //TODO: WriteTo; ReadFrom (i.e. multicast server)
    }
}
```

This is an example how the library is used (TCP):

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 33333);
server.Start();
Task<TcpConnection> acceptClient = Task<TcpConnection>.Run(() => {
    return new TcpConnection(server.AcceptSocket());
});
TcpConnection myConnection = new TcpConnection("127.0.0.1", 33333);
myConnection.PacketHandler = MessageHandler;

TcpConnection serverSideConnection = acceptClient.Result; 
serverSideConnection.WritePacket(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, world!"));

Console.ReadKey(true);

static void MessageHandler(ReadOnlySpan<byte> packet, PacketArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received message of len {0} from server!", packet.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet));
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I'll find the time to go through this, but at first glance I already saw `#region Private Fields` which contains three `protected` properties with inconsistent naming ( `Socket` vs `_remoteEndpoint` ). (FYI fields should never be `protected`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/field .) I also see pointless abbreviations: `Socket s`.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Great, thanks! I did't really think of the protected fields the same way as of the public fields, I must admit...

Comment: @BCdotWEB any update on this? I totally understand if you don't find the time to go through all this, could you point me somewhere else I could ask?